# How can I check to see if a div contains an image element in JavaScript? (Not like a background image, like the element contained)

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I have a fairly simple program which moves a picture of a house between 6 different tiles. The goal here is as follows:

- When I drag a house on to an empty grass cell, I want the house to move to that cell. (This is already working.)
- When I drag a house onto a cell containing a house, I want something special to happen. (Call a function)

Here's my code:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

function yeet() {
  alert("ekfui");
}
```

```css
.cell {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-image: url("https://us.123rf.com/450wm/tuulijumala/tuulijumala1602/tuulijumala160200015/52473977-seamless-square-green-grass-texture-.jpg?ver=6");
}
```

```html
<!--What you actually see-->
<div align="center">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="gh" class="cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img src="http://worldartsme.com/images/free-house-clipart-1.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="100px" height="100px">
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="cell" ondrop="drop(event); yeet();" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img src="http://worldartsme.com/images/free-house-clipart-1.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="100px" height="100px">
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

No jQuery or libraries please

Comment: check that div children `.children` should return a list of all children the div  has.

Answer (score 0):

In your drop function, check if event `currentTarget` contains any `img` tags:

```
if (ev.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('img').length > 0) {
  alert('There\'s already a house there.');
} else {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xmdkj0y4/